# How to end a user session based on specific user id in PASSPORTJS. Kick any user I want etc

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js

I'd like to select any userid and be able to end their user sesion, aka log them out.

The only thing I see in the docs is a req.logout() but that only works for current user aka ME.

```
// logout
userController.logout = function (req, res) {
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/main');
};

module.exports = userController;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I had to use connect-mongostore to store the sessions of each user when they log in. Then I use the existing mongoose connection to do a raw mongodb query to delete a specific user session based on username, after pressing the ban button and an ajax post request to send the user info. They will be logged out the next thing they try to do that requires user information on the site.

Can't believe no one here even offered a beginning step to this easy solution 8 days later...L.O.Lx100

L.O.L @ the guy thinking mongodb tag isn't relevant here. Kinda need it to remove user sessions buddy.
R.o.f.L @ the guy who edited the nodejs tag out of this as well, is an app.js file found anywhere else other than nodejs buddy? Is express also found in anywhere else other than nodejs?
Comedians on this site are of good quality.

Code to help anyone else:

In app.js:

```
    var session = require('express-session');
    var MongoStore = require('connect-mongostore')(session);
    app.use(require('express-session')({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new MongoStore({mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection})

}));
```

in my controller file:

```
mongoose.connection.db.collection('sessions').deleteMany({

            "session.passport.user": username


        })
```